# Bad Gateway / Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map x bytes

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, memory, server

So sometimes I was getting a bad gateway error from a server when running a Jenkins job, and recently 'sometimes' became 'always'. We managed to find that it was most likely cause by:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000008c900000, 113246208, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 113246208 bytes for committing reserved memory.
An error report file with more information is saved as:
//hs_err_pid33.log
[ timer expired, abort... ]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I run `free -m` I get:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7687        5983         209          83        1494        1248
Swap:             0           0           0
```

When I run `less /proc/meminfo` I get:

```
MemTotal:        7872324 kB
MemFree:          210708 kB
MemAvailable:    1281020 kB
Buffers:          346224 kB
Cached:           754116 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          6580964 kB
Inactive:         526484 kB
Active(anon):    6012832 kB
Inactive(anon):    82220 kB
Active(file):     568132 kB
Inactive(file):   444264 kB
Unevictable:        3652 kB
Mlocked:            3652 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               284 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       6010792 kB
Mapped:           102896 kB
Shmem:             85520 kB
Slab:             436552 kB
SReclaimable:     362696 kB
SUnreclaim:        73856 kB
KernelStack:       14336 kB
PageTables:        22640 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3936160 kB
Committed_AS:    9303016 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      419816 kB
DirectMap2M:     7661568 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

The job in configured that `JAVA_OPTS: '-server -Xmx512m -Dlogging.config=/config/log/logback.xml'` Increasing `-Xmx512m` to `-Xmx1024m` did not help. Also, there are more Jenkins build triggered one after another.

Would be thankful for tips what to try / check to fix this.

Edit: when I run `top -o RES` I got:

```
Tasks: 183 total,   1 running, 182 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  7872324 total,   242744 free,  6122952 used,  1506628 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  1282492 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                 
16119 root      20   0 4766892 1.029g  16536 S   0.0 13.7   3:18.00 java                                                                                                                                    
16095 root      20   0 4754704 1.014g  16640 S   0.0 13.5   2:26.41 java                                                                                                                                    
16022 root      20   0 3595076 590968  16580 S   0.0  7.5   2:00.92 java                                                                                                                                    
15912 root      20   0 3083232 504068  16024 S   0.0  6.4   3:08.03 java                                                                                                                                    
16067 root      20   0 3106944 483148  16732 S   0.0  6.1   1:44.71 java                                                                                                                                    
16037 root      20   0 3039324 464488  16692 S   0.0  5.9   1:37.74 java                                                                                                                                    
16082 root      20   0 3111044 464216  16656 S   0.0  5.9   1:43.01 java                                                                                                                                    
16032 root      20   0 3026936 427452  16040 S   0.0  5.4   1:31.43 java                                                                                                                                    
15926 root      20   0 3118228 419600  16608 S   0.0  5.3   2:45.84 java                                                                                                                                    
15967 root      20   0 3016596 357356  16472 S   0.0  4.5   1:20.40 java                                                                                                                                    
 1113 root      20   0 2520832 121108   1376 S   0.0  1.5 605:52.95 dockerd
```

Comment: It's not really a mystery. You're running out of memory. Your workload has grown, and so has the occurrence of that problem. You'll need to make sure your server isn't trying trying to do too many things in parallel, or get some more memory. If you think you have enough memory, then make sure you aren't restricting it accidentally in something like docker. Note that the `mmap` is allocating native memory, so `-Xmx` doesn't affect that.

Comment: Did you consider give any swap space?

Comment: @Volkan - I did, but decided to search for the reason first. What would you recommend?

Comment: @Kayaman - so ```-Xms``` won't do nothing either? Do you know what's the good way to track execution of server's actions? Those Java processes are suspicious, they sum up to 74.2% of memory usage.

Comment: Well, that's the job of your sysadmin (or "devops engineer" as they're called these days). If you don't have one, then you or some other person is going to start learning some new things (i.e. Jenkins configuration, if that's not clear). You can of course try to add swap space as a quick fix, but those tend to explode in your face later with bigger consequences. You might be able to get away easier by just limiting parallel jobs (with possible longer build times as a result).